Move the table to the extreme right hand side of the screen
I have two div rows defines and have some elements constrained to it as shown in the code snippet below. The code snippet is not working (showing the jqxwidget library table) as expected for unknown reason as I have the same code working here in this JSFiddle.Hence, I've included the fiddle in this post. In the JSFiddle above, it is currently showing like this:

But I want it to be like this (edited version of image below):

Is it possible to achieve the same with two rows approach?


$('[name="seqlineupspendinglist"]').select2();

var source = {
  localdata: "",
  datafields: [{
    name: 'Name',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'Color',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'plateName',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'date',
    type: 'date'
  }],
  datatype: "array"
};

var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
  width: 500,
  theme: 'energyblue',
  source: adapter,
  sortable: true,
  ready: function() {
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('focus');
  },
  columns: [{
    text: 'Name',
    datafield: 'Name',
    columngroup: 'Name',
    width: 90
  }, {
    text: 'Color',
    columngroup: 'Color',
    datafield: 'Color',
    width: 90
  }, {
    text: 'Plate Name',
    datafield: 'plateName',
    width: 170
  }, {
    text: 'Date',
    datafield: 'date',
    width: 160,
    cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
  }]
});
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.block {
  padding: 5px 1%;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 22px;
  /* so same height as select */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 28px;
  /* so button is same height as select and inputs */
  margin-right: 100px
}

select {
  width: 150px;
  /* so --Please Select-- text is all visible */
}
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="startLane">Select Dropdown:</label>
    <select name="seqlineupspendinglist">
      <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="startLane">Starting Lane #:</label>
    <input type="text" id="startLane" name="startLane" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="endLane">Ending Lane #:</label>
    <input type="text" id="endLane" name="endLane" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="submit" value="Show Cases" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      <label class="label">Information:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="startLane">Second Row Test</label>
    <input type="text" id="startLane" name="startLane" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="startLane">Second Row Test</label>
    <input type="text" id="startLane" name="startLane" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <label class="label" for="endLane">Second Row Test</label>
    <input type="text" id="endLane" name="endLane" />
  </div>

</div>




Notice in the Stack Snippet that the page isn't loading that plugin on <div id="jqxgrid"></div>? Moreover, the bottom row of <input>s are now directly adjacent to the top row of <input>s.  1. Try wrapping both <div class="row"> together in a <div>.  2. Move <div id="jqxgrid"></div>  out of the new <div> and put it under the new <div>. 3. Use grid, or/and flex layout on a element that contains both <div>s so that they sit side-by-side (inline).

https://jsfiddle.net/c35vygqz/

If the problem is just with the layout, I think you can easily fix it with CSS Grid. Here are some links to help you: CSS Tricks, W3S, MDN Web Docs
